# How to save results of a database query in a file without querying twice.?

Tags: django

I have my views showing a large number of results which have come from some query like :

```
return render(request, 'all_interviews.html', {'filter': interview_filter, 'interviews': page_interviews})
```

I am showing the results on the frontend . Now I want to provide a "**Download result**s" button which will write all the results in a file (can be csv, excel ) .

I can do that by calling a function that again calls the same query , then write them in the file. How can I avoid running the query twice ?

Some ideas I thought:
Use memcache (I don't have any clue if it is possible to save huge lists).

Comment: You might need to clarify with more code. QuerySets in Django do not involve db activity until they are evaluated. Chaining filters does not result in a database hit. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy

Comment: How frequently data that have to be downloaded being changed?

Comment: You could use this -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/#filesystem-caching

Comment: @Satevg...Barely...only in days..